# How to send a Base64 encoded image via PHP?

Tags: php, curl, base64

I would like to send an image via PHP/cURL as a Base64 encode string instead of using the `file_get_contents` part.
How to do that?

```
$headers = array("Host" => "http://api.tumblr.com/", "Content-type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Expect" => "");

$params = array("data" => array(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/photo/happyholidays.jpg")),"type" => "photo");

oauth_gen("POST", "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/$blogname/post", $params, $headers);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TestApp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/$blogname/post");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: " . $headers['Authorization'],
    "Content-type: " . $headers["Content-type"],
    "Expect: ")
);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the image by anyhow to get the image's byte data. Only then you can convert the byte data into base64 easily. So far my knowledge, you can not send(http post) the bytes directly from a link(image).

```
$params = array("data" => base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/photo/happyholidays.jpg")),"type" => "photo");
```

If you don't want to read the image using **file_get_contents** then use **curl** to get the byte data for the image.

Comment: Since its only one image, it will not make any difference. Also, how the "data" in $params is handled is depends upon the function oauth_gen() which is obscure here!